# ASP.NET not working for IE 10 on production but development

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a weird problem. I have a ASP.NET website that is working fine on my local development environment but stuck on the production. After I exam, both environment use the same code. The detail is: when using IE 10 to open my website from production server, the index page keeps loading forever.

I have to switch my browser mode from IE 10 to IE 10 Compat View to make it work.

But the website runs without any issue if I run through my local machine.

What may be the problems that freeze my page?

Thank you,

Comment: My only assumption is it is going into infinite loop of redirects, somehow. You should check all your IE specific code

Comment: Maybe the IIS settings are different from your localhost to production

Comment: You should use the developer tools to find out what kind of errors you are getting. There is not enough information provided here to debug your issue.

Comment: The might be authorization problems